# Excel 2013 VBA: Combination of IF and VLookUP named range and return value if criteria is met

Tags: vba, if-statement, vlookup

Thank you for looking at my question.

Objective:
I need VBA to look up the date in Column **B** in the "Heat Map Data" sheet, using a named range (refer 1st image below - Calendar named Range) and if the date matches the date in the Calendar, then I want the values entered into the columns **L, M, N, O,** and **P**.

Currently it is a manual process using the following formula example for each of the columns *=IF($B2="","",VLOOKUP($B2,CALENDAR_from_2013_to_2019,4,0))* (in this formula returning Day Type).

1st image shows the Calendar named ranges data type.
[image]
2nd image shows the sheet where I'd like VBA to return the values into appropriate columns.
[image]

I have tried to search the net to see if I could find a solution that I could manipulate to my needs, but this hasn't been successful. I get somewhat confused by the code and how to formulated it to my needs.

I'd be most grateful if someone would be able to direct me to a solution. 
Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
TheShyButterfly

Comment: This isn't how Stack Overflow works, this is *too broad* to be answerable; it's not a question, it's a request for code. You have to *try* to do it yourself. When you're stuck on a *specific* issue, *then* you have a SO question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to use VBA if you have a vlookup which does what you need.  I wouldn't describe it as a "manual process" as you simply need to autofill your formula down each column to get the required data.  I would change the formula slightly to iferror(vlookup...),"") so you don't have to check for a value in column B.